# Swift: Changing view/screen depending on device orientation. What is "efficiency wise" the better option?

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, landscape-portrait, device-orientation

### Introduction

I'm creating a calendar app in which one of the screens has a landscape view and a portrait view. For simplicity picture the iOS apple calendar in which the landscape view is a week view (i.e. completely different than the portrait view).

#### Issue

I'm getting a sense of bad code structure and potential loss of efficiency in my current code. Since I basically use the users battery and CPU for the week view concurrently with the portrait view even though not everyone uses the week view. *What is the better practice in implementing a different presentation depending on device rotation?*

#### Question

- *Which pattern would be the more efficient approach? Is there a third option I haven't considered that would result in better performance?*

**My attempts**

(I've also included a code example (below) that shows my implementation of these attempts in code.)

1. Two `UIViewController`s that is segued and "popped" depending on conditions of device orientation in `viewWillTransition()`. Although that became quickly out of hand since the method triggers in all view controller currently in memory/navigationStack, resulting in additional copies of viewControllers in the navigation stack if you swap between right landscape and left landscape.
2. Using one `UIViewController` and two `UIView` subclass that is initialized and communicating to the view controller through the delegate-protocol pattern. In which during the `viewWillTransition()` I simply animate an alpha change between the two `UIViews` depending on the device orientation.

#### Code example

(I have provided two simplification to illustrate my attempts described above, methods such as dataSource and delegate methods for UICollectionViews are not included are not included in the example below.)

**Attempt 1:**

```
class PortraitCalendar: UIViewController {
    let portraitCalendarView : MonthCalendar = {
        // Setup of my portrait calendar, it is a UICollectionView subclass.
    }
    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         view.addSubview(portraitCalendarView)
         // Additional setup..
     }
     
     override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
         super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
         if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLandscapeCalendar", sender: nil)
         } 
     }
 }

 class LandscapeCalendar: UIViewController {
     let landscapeView : LandscapeView = {
          // Setup of the landscape view, a UICollectionView subclass.
     }
     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         view.addSubview(landscapeView)
         // Additional setup..
     }
     
     override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
         super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
         if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
              navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
         } 
     }
 }
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
class PortraitCalendar: UIViewController, LandscapeCalendarDelegate {
    let portraitCalendarView : MonthCalendar = {
        // Setup of my portrait calendar, it is a UICollectionView subclass.
    }

    // UIView subclass with a UICollectionView within it as a week calendar.
    let landscapeCalendar = LandscapeView() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(portraitCalendarView)
        view.addSubview(landscapeCalendar)
        landscapeCalendar.alpha = 0
        portraitCalendarView.alpha = 1
        // Constraints and additional setup as well of course.
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            landscapeCalendarDelegate?.splitCalendarViewWillAppear()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.portraitCalendarView.alpha = 0
                self.landscapeCalendar.alpha = 1
            }
        } else {
            self.portraitCalendarView.alpha = 1
            self.landscapeCalendar.alpha = 0
        }
     }
}
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd definitely go for an option **number 2**.

That way you encapsulate all the *logic* related to the calendar, for example for adding event or displaying it, in one view controller, without the need to reimplement the sane logic somewhere else (eg other view controller with landscape mode). Having two views for a different layout modes is not *THAT* easy to maintain, but if that's the only way to show the difference between the modes it really is a fine solution. And it's much easier to maintain than two view controllers with the very similar logic.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! Yes I agree, the first attempt quickly gave some strange behaviors. The problem I see with the 2nd attempt though, is that I basically need a protocol for each as well as having them both loaded in memory and running concurrently. I haven't tested them through CPU/memory usage, **but** I feel that since not everyone will use the week view of the calendar, I basically use their battery and CPU for it anyway. Is there a third option that would be more "intelligent" CPU wise?

Comment: @theoadahl trust me having two views, even complex ones in memory is nothing big of a resource if they're coded properly. Also you don't always need delegation pattern to handle the work of your views. You could easily use closures or protocols (in a contract meaning of it). Performance wise I really doubt that having just two views in memory gonna cause some issues. If you're not interacting with those views, they also have no impact on CPU and battery life. So if you have one active view, only its interactions are counted.

Comment: Ok i've played around with the second attempt and just like you said it doesn't seem to impact performance that much. Thank you for the insight. Cheers.